# pgr_dijkstra function with geometry column in result

Tags: geometry, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting, dijkstra

can you help me to edit my pgr_dijkstra function to required result?

Currently I had this select:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('
SELECT gid AS id,
     source,
     target,
     cost,
     reverse_cost,
     the_geom
    FROM pgr.ways',
30623, 
30593, directed := true)
```

and my result is like this:

[image]

What I need to do to fill geometry column?

I've tried add join to table ways by edge id, but I want to be sure that is not exist solution without join.

Answer (score 5):

Join to table ways is as for now only solution (BTW recommended in all official documentation and [workshops](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.1.0-dev/en/chapters/wrapper.html#one-route-geometry))